# What is a better alternative to posting JSON results?

Tags: jquery, html, css, json, jquery-ui

I am creating a stock widget: http://jsfiddle.net/thetuneupguy/h6RB8/

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%20in(%22GCF14.CMX%22%2C%22SIF14.CMX%22%2C%22PAH14.NYM%22%2C%22PLF14.NYM%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=', function(data) {

        console.log(data.query.results.quote);
        $.each(data.query.results.quote,function(key,val){
            var items = [];
            $.each(val,function(name,value){
                items.push('<li>' +name+ ' : '+ value + '</li>');
            });
            $('<ul/>', {'class': 'my-new-list',html: items.join('')}).appendTo('#blk-1');
        });

    });
});
```

I want to know if there is a better way to display my results so that I can then format/style them to fit them into my widget design. Thanks!

Comment: Assign classes to all the elements, so the user can use CSS to style them.

Comment: @Barmar What's wrong with `.my-new-list li` to style the elements? I agree a table could be used, or wrap name/value in `<span>` to allow a CSS selector

Answer (score 0):

Hey does this help you? Let me know if it works:

http://answers.squarespace.com/questions/3388/how-can-i-access-and-style-json-content

Answer (score 0):

It looks nobody understood you xD. Here you have:

```
    $.each(data.query.results.quote, function(key, obj){
        var $tr = $('<tr/>', {'class': 'my-new-list'}).appendTo('#blk-1 table');            
        $tr.append($('<td/>').text(obj.Name || "-"));
        $tr.append($('<td/>').text(obj.Ask || "-"));
        $tr.append($('<td/>').text(obj.Bid || "-"));
        $tr.append($('<td/>').text(obj.Change || "-"));
        $tr.append($('<td/>').text(obj.ChangeinPercent || "-"));
    });
```

As you see, we don't traverse the number of columns because we have them well defined in the table header

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/h6RB8/2/

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: the other responses are what I was looking for, but you went above and beyond. I decided to give your answer a try, though, so thanks! If I wanted to grab the various names for the symbols and rename them, what's the best route with the answer you've provided (I.e. Gold Jan 14 --> Gold)?

Comment: You mean to have the table header titles dynamically filled?

Comment: Presently, each symbol has a name, per .Name. I want to be able to modify that name and display the results. So, for the symbol GCF14.CMX the name is Gold Jan 14. I want the name to be Gold. I need to change the name for each symbol.